# Any reason to avoid Application.Worksheetfunction?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am writing a macro to iterate over some records and wanted to a for-loop to avoid any chance of infinite while looping like:

```
For i = 0 to COUNT
  **do stuff with START_CELL.Offset(i,0)
Next
```

I couldn't remember how to do a count of things from VBA so a search sent me here: [Use VBA to Count Non Blank Cells in a Column](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/32797-use-visual-basic-applications-count-non-blank-cells-column.html).  One suggestion was

```
n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

This seemed over complicated, so I did some more digging and decided I was going to use:

```
COUNT = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(COUNT_RANGE)
```

Another example on that page used `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA()`, but still now I am concerned (paranoid) there is a reason I should avoid it.  Are there any?

Thanks all.

Comment: There is no reason to avoid using worksheet functions.

Comment: Keep `WorksheetFunction` as they are very efficient. Keep only in mind the difference between these two: `Application.Count()` and `WorksheetFunction.Count()`- if any error they will behave differently. You could also try to get last row in this way: `lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row` but it's difficult to decide which option is best not seeing your data sheet.

Comment: Thanks again.  I feel better now :)  In my head, VBA is separate from Excel enough that communication would be slow(er).  I like writing macros that take more than 60 seconds, so I try to think about performance ahead of time.

Comment: if you want to iterate over all cells within the filled range then Count may not be what you want (if you have any blank cells within the range then you won't be looping over what you want). For any case where you want to cover the 'entire' used portion of the column then using a .End(xlUp) method as suggested by @KazJaw is more appropriate. If you want to restrict a loop to, say, only cells with formulae, or only cells with constant values, or a union of the two, then using the SpecialCells method you point out is best and fastest as it will skip wasting time on blank cells.

Comment: (ran out of space...) Every query of a range has a pretty large overhead (small for a few, but if you do it a thousand times you will notice the execution time for sure) so, if you have to loop over cells to change properties etc (instead of loading range data into an array in a batch), then it is definitely wise to spend a few more CPU cycles narrowing down the range for the loop -> SpecialCells, or any other 'refinement' to the number of the cells you actually have to loop over is well worth it. If you know you have a contiguous range, then WorksheetFunction.CountA is fine.

Comment: OK, for most VBA projects I agree with the comments of @tigeravatar and @KazJaw. Having said that, if you can code efficiently something that a `worksheetfunction` does, and you are going to use it a lot in your code, go ahead and code it yourself. See http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices.aspx (under "other performance optimizations") and here http://www.avdf.com/apr98/art_ot003.html (under Tip 3).

Comment: I had lots of problems using `WorksheetFunction`, in Excel 2000. Methods raised error. I agree, however, that they are more efficient then looping through cells!

Comment: @Ioannis Thank you for the links.  The note about coding a function yourself is particularly helpful in answering my questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only show-stopper reason to avoid worksheet functions is if you are worried about backwards compatibility with older versions of Excel. New versions of Excel generally introduce new worksheet functions. If these aren't available in your users' versions of Excel you will run into difficulties.

Other than that, and if you know the functions are available on the version your users are working with, they are generally very efficient and often quicker than the equivalent in VBA, especially if they avoid looping through cells, as mentioned in the comments.