# WorksheetFunction to determine column and use result as range

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

First of all here's a link to my workbook, uploaded to OneDrive:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsQuasddi71ugRSDelemaNIBKazB

I have been trying for the past couple of weeks to develop a code, to search out a Header in a column, to determine the range of what I want to copy.

The result I get in Excel:
To find column letter for "No.":

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH("No.";1:1;0);4);"1";"")
```

**Result: B**

To find columns header and first row for "No.":

```
=ADDRESS(1;MATCH("No.";1:1;0);4)
```

**Result: B1**

To find column letter for "Prepayment Amount excl VAT":

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH("Prepayment Amount excl VAT";1:1;0);4);"1";"")
```

**Result: L**

To find columns header and first row for "Prepayment Amount excl VAT":

```
=ADDRESS(1;MATCH("Prepayment Amount excl VAT";1:1;0);4)
```

**Result: L1**

Within the excel file, I have two modules... Module1 is working based on the columns, meaning it will always copy column B and L in Sheet 1, and column A and B in sheet 2...

In Module2 I have been trying to create a macro, which should navigate on the Header name of the column, and return cell B1 and column B to declare the column as:

```
sht.Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Copy
```

Otherwise I would like to assign the Substitute, Address, Match formula to a variable, which I want to replace "B1" and "B" with...

At the moment I get a lot of errors...

Am I able to make the macro use the result of my substitute, address, match formula, to replace "B1" and "B" in `sht.Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Copy`?

Please let me know, if you have an idea, of how I can correct the macro to do as I want it to :)

My macro is as listed below:

```
Sub CopyPasteDataLookingForHeader()
Dim sht, sht2, sht3 As Worksheet
Dim i, LastRow, LastRow2 As Long
Dim Number, NumberOne, Prepay, PrepayOne As Variant
Set sht = Sheets("Sales List")
Set sht2 = Sheets("Match Sales List and Pivot")
Set sht3 = Sheets("Pivot of Prepayment account")
Number = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(sht.Range("1:1").Address(1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("No.", sht.Range("1:1"), 0), 4), 1, "")
NumberOne = sht.Range("1:1").Address(1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("No.", sht.Range("1:1"), 0), 4)
Prepay = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(sht.Range("1:1").Address(1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Prepayment Amount excl VAT", sht.Range("1:1"), 0), 4), "1", "")
PrepayOne = sht.Range("1:1").Address(1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Prepayment Amount excl VAT", sht.Range("1:1"), 0), 4)
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, Number).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = sht3.Cells(sht3.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
rng1 = "NumberOne:Number"
rng2 = "PrepayOne:Prepay"

sht.Range(rng1 & LastRow).Copy
sht2.Activate
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'------------------------------------------
sht.Range(rng2 & LastRow).Copy
sht2.Activate
Range("E1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'------------------------------------------
sht3.Range("A1:A" & LastRow2).Copy
sht2.Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'------------------------------------------
sht3.Range("B1:B" & LastRow2).Copy
sht2.Activate
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'------------------------------------------
Columns("A:E").ColumnWidth = 25
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think I understood your question completely but can't you simply use an if statement and use columns based on a condition?

Comment: I suggest you use the Range.Find method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referencing variables, don't put them in quotations. Right now, the code has `rng1 = "NumberOne:Number"`, which Excel interprets literally. You'll want to concatenate the pieces of text to form the range. Try:

```
Dim FindNo, Number, NumberOne, FindPrepay, Prepay, PrepayOne As String

FindNo = Sht.Range("1:1").Find("No.").Address(False, False, xlA1)
Number = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindNo, 1, "")
NumberOne = FindNo

FindPrepay = Sht.Range("1:1").Find("Prepayment Amount excl VAT").Address(False, False, xlA1)
Prepay = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindPrepay, 1, "")
PrepayOne = FindPrepay

rng1 = NumberOne & ":" & Number & LastRow
rng2 = PrepayOne & ":" & Prepay & LastRow
```

This also uses the VBA `Range.Find`, and `Address` methods, instead of calling worksheet functions.

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for!
Works perfectly, thank you very much.
So for the future, I should try to find VBA's own method, instead of WorksheetFunction? :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. And not necessarily. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18521640/7787878). I personally avoid `WorksheetFunction.Match`, as I've had mixed results using it. The other thing to note was there was some syntax issues with the way you were calling `Address` in your code. VBA `Address` is a bit different from the worksheet function `Address`, which (to my knowledge) is not available in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I completely understand your question, but I recently developed a data-validation drop down box that may answer your question.

I have two sheets.  Sheet1.Column "A" is employee names.  Range("B1") has a drop down box with header names from the 2nd sheet which is called "DataBase"

Sheet("DataBase") also has the same employee names in Column "A".  But it also has "Phone Number" in column "B", "Address" in column "C", "Next of Kin" in column "D", and so forth.  The top row of Sheet("DataBase") has header names corresponding to the names in quotation marks above.

On sheet1 create a validation list-box in "B1" by selecting "B1" and clicking Data menu -> Validation.  Choose "List" in the window and select the headers of the 2nd sheet, - Sheet("DataBase"), as the list for the list box.  Then simply put the following code in Sheet1's module: (Of course you will have to change the header names and columns to fit your own project, but this will give you an idea as to how to get different ranges, copy them to other destinations.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LR As Long
Dim myRng As Range

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet2.Activate

    LR = lastRowCol(Sheet2, "B")

    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 2 Then

        Select Case Target.Value

            Case "Date of Birth"
                Set myRng = Sheet2.Range("B2:B" & LR)

            Case "Phone Number"
                Set myRng = Sheet2.Range("C2:C" & LR)

            Case "Seniority Date"
                Set myRng = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D" & LR)

            Case "Next of Kin"
                Set myRng = Sheet2.Range("E2:E" & LR)

        End Select

    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheet1.Range("B2:B5000").ClearContents
    myRng.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
    Sheet1.Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub




Function lastRowCol(sht1 As Worksheet, col As String) As Long
lastRowCol = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```